# Tap keeps dripping even after reseating - broken?

Tags: plumbing, washer, taps

I've replaced the washer in the tap and used a reseating tool, but when I feel with my finger there's what appears to be a "notch" in the area the tap washer would be pressing down on. Picture is attached.

Is this tap effectively broken? I'm wondering whether I should just replace it rather than continuing to try and repair what is a pretty old tap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your excellent picture shows that the seat in this valve is not smooth and planar all the way around. With that said it looks like this valve is definitely in line for replacement.

As a temporary work around you may want to see if you can find a faucet washer that is made of silicon instead of the normally much harder faucet washer material. It may be able to squeeze down on the imperfect seat and seal off the faucet till you can make the full replacement. Do not wait too long however because the turning under pressure to close the faucet with a silicon washer is likely to degrade and tear up the washer surface.

Comment: Would a more aggressive "reseating" be worthwhile?

Comment: @JPhi1618 - I do not know the real answer to your re-seating question. It depends on factors such as type of tool you have, now much material would have to be removed to create a good seat and quality of the valve material itself. For a glib answer I'd say that since it appears that replacement is highly likely why not try it and see what happens. Just be careful not to reduce the structural integrity of the valve too much.

Comment: @JPhi1618 After using the reseating tool twice, and comparing how much material was removed versus the depth of the "notch" in the valve seat, I'd have to remove all of the raised ring area and then some of the wider lower ring. A pair of replacement taps would be quite cheap since we're not after anything fancy so I think that will be my choice of action but I wouldn't rule out a really aggressive reseating fixing it for a while.

Comment: @MattJones, thanks for the update - I was just curious.  A lot of times its more about how hard the valve is to replace rather than cost, but if it's not that big of a deal, I'd just replace it too.

Comment: Valve seats are most effective when the part that interacts with the rubber washer is minimal as opposed to maximal. A narrow ring can squeeze into the washer and create a seal with less pressure than a much wider seat surface. The compliance and compression of the rubber ring are what creates the seal.